# excel - group sheets by columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a bunch of .csv files with the same structure, but it's not guaranteed that they are in same order row-wise. I would like to group them all in a single spreadsheet. The following image draws the issue:

[image]

Ps: the example shows 2 tables in the same spreadsheet only for examplification.

I'm using Excel from Office 2016 edition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`/`MATCH` it may do what you want

Comment: Thanks, `VLOOKUP` will do the trick. Feel free to send an answer so i can green-check it.

Answer (score 1):

VLookup is great for looking up a single column, but doing it for multiple columns is tedious.

INDEX / MATCH would be a better fit for handling multiple columns. It splits the functionality of VLOOKUP into 2 steps. This allows she workbook to perform faster and makes the formulas easier to write.

[image: Excel Index-Match Example]

In this example, I've got the source sheets on the left in blue and green, and the result on the right in gray. The formulas for the first row of data are above the result table.

First, use =MATCH to find the row number of the referenced data in a source sheet. In the example, in J3, MATCH looks up the value "a" in the array "A:A" and finds it in row 3. Similarly, K3 looks up "a" in "E:E" and finds it in row 5.

Now that we know the row, we can look up specific values in columns easily. In the example, L3 looks in array "B:B" for row 3 (from J3), and M3 looks in "F:F" for row 5 (from K3). Repeat for all the columns that you need, and then drag down the whole row to fill in the sheet.

As you can see Index/Match is a little bit more complicated than Vlookup. However, separating the slow Match from the fast Index allows the sheet to perform more efficiently, and the INDEX calls are easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to get the result:

1. Import 2 tables to Power Query Editor, select the Range- go to **Data**- select **From Table/Range**- close **Power Query Editor** and select **keep**- select another Range and repeat steps to import to Editor:

[image]

2. Select **Table 3**- and go to **Home**- **Combine**- select **Merge Queries**- select the matching columns- then **Close & Load to...**:
   [image]